# rails/jquery/ajax: done callback is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I had working code where an AJAX call which didn't require a return value was working correctly.

Javascript (actually coffeescript):

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/images/" + image_id + "/" + action,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done( (response) ->
      alert("hello")
      )
```

At server side I had this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render nothing: true}
end
```

This was working fine

But now I need to return a value, so I changed server side to this:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => @image.quality}
end
```

This also executes fine, no errors server-side nor client-side - but the "done" callback never executes.

What am I missing? I searched lots of docs and I am confused about what I've found. The official docs http://www.railscook.com/recipes/rails-view-controller-ajax-response-example/ say to render js with a template but I don't need to render javascript directly, I just need a value at client-side.

Comment: If you inspect the response using your browser Developer Tools, do you see any response with the expected json ? What about any JavaScript errors in the Console window ?

Comment: Actually I do see the json response when I look at firebug in the console section and the response tab! So it seems the response arrives - but then why doesn't `done` fire? Should I use another callback?

Comment: I like the `$.get` function, it's short and always works for me, try that:  `$.get(url, function(response) { alert("got it!"); });` - you just need to set the `url` variable before calling it

Comment: Also try `success` callback in your case, see if it fires.

Comment: none of your suggestions work....tried the get shortcut and the success callback :(

Comment: `.done(` is missing closing parens

Comment: You are right that done is missing the closing bracket, but it's actually there in the code. Going to edit the post. jquery version is 1.11.1, accessed through the rails gem jquery-rails

Comment: This is driving me nuts. In the console I can read 
GET http://localhost:3000/images/106/set_good 200 OK 312ms and the response is there if I go into firebug to the response tab - but the callback doesn't fire!!!

Comment: For debugging purpose you can include the `async: false` option in the `$.ajax` function to stop the Javascript from continuing its execution until a response is returned. to make sure nothing is breaking afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Dam it.

The problem was that the JSON was malformed.

For some reason

```
format.json {render :json => @image.quality}
```

doesn't produce valid json, and actually, not the done callback, but the error callback would fire...(very bad practice from my side to not have included an error callback in the first place)

So if I change this to

```
format.json {render json: @image}
```

I get valid json and the done callback fires...

Comment: I should've asked you to include error callback, I assumed your response was ok since you could verify it using Firebug. Anyway good learning session :)